# How to send Class object of a Java class over network

Tags: java, classloader

I need to send `Class` object of a Java class from one JVM on a host to a JVM on another host. What is a good way to do it? I'm trying `ByteArrayOutputStream` but it didn't work properly, i.e. the server side couldn't load it in JVM using classloader.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you looked into using serialization?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen of course, I'm using Serialization. `ByteArrayOutputStream` is the class passed to `ObjectOutputStream` in my case.

Comment: I stopped doing this (shipping classes) and started shipping actual source code in my Java dialect (JavaX). Much easier this way, you never have to go down to bytecode level.

Comment: Let your class implements Serializable interface and be sure that serialVersionUID is the same on both systems. Then use writeObject and readObject of ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream. It works.

Comment: Can you add the stack trace that is generated?  Can you add the source code that you've implemented?

Comment: Take a look at the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601251/java-custom-class-loader-issue/47736120#47736120.  It is an implementation that you can use to send class files over the wire.